# javascript auto fill form extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a page and i wan't to fill it with my data. (Auto filling chrome extension).
I tried to work with vanilla javascript and JQuery, but they both don't work.

Here is my code:

```
$('#control_8 option[value=14401]').attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');
```

Here i use trigger(), so after a option is selected, in it subcategory it will load all items. 
When i run this code in the console - it works. But if i run it from the chrome extension, it selects but trigger doesn't work. 
SOS.

Comment: When does the chrome extension execute the code? Is the DOM actually fully loaded when it does? Can you use `$(document).ready()` in there to delay the execution?

Comment: Yes. I tried with it also, also i added setTimeout function, but still doesn't work...

Comment: I had a similar problem with an extension I wrote the other day, for me. The 'change' handler called  a function that did some computation and rendered the output to the dom. The extension can't reach that computation code since extensions are in isolated worlds on different threads. The javascript can affect the html and inject css but it can't tamper with the javascript that is on the page. Is that the problem  you are having?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a selector issue with your trigger function.
Split the code and try the trigger function in following way

```
$('#control_8 option[value=14401]').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('Your selector').trigger('change');
```